# How does desktop app store password safety

Tags: security

I was wondering, whether there is a known safe way to store username and password safely for desktop application.

For example, the open source [KeyPass](http://keepass.info/help/base/faq_tech.html)

Let's say I get access to user local computer, grab all its KeyPass's configuration files, and step through KeyPass source code, is that I can reverse the user username and password after then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is the concept of a one-way function.  That is, if we have the relationship

`y = f(x)`

And we know `y` and `f`, it might still take a lot of time and effort to find `x`.

Example one-way functions (as far as we know they are, at least...) are the SHA algorithms.

Comment: Only the master password is hashed - everything else is symmetrically encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

KeePass keeps all the data symmetrically encrypted in a local store via AES so unless you get hold of the master password, your chances of decryption are pretty minuscule. The master password itself is stored as a SHA-256 hash (I assume salted) which means that so long as it has good entropy to begin with, your chances of getting hold of it are about the same as breaking the encryption.

So yes, this is a very safe way of storing credentials. Not foolproof, but about as good as you practically get.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a password safely by using, say, a well known strong encryption algorithm, like AES.

HOWEVER, you cannot make the procedure that depends on the password 100% secure. Since the actual functionality of a desktop app is right inside the app's code, there will always be a way for the attacker to access that without even needing to know your password. Even using polymorphic self modifying code based on the encrypted key is still crackable (that is actually a protection that CuteFTP was using in the past, but still just xoring user's ftp passwords to store them 'safely').

Bearing that in mind, encryption does make it more difficult and at least, even if people crack the app, they may not be able to recover your original password.